# Parent html element ignoring padding of child

Tags: html, css

How do I get a parent element (example here - `<header>`) without its own padding to include a child element's padding (example here - `<h1>`) in its height?

If I added 1px of padding to my parent element, then it includes both its own and the child's padding.  But without its own padding, it ignores the child padding.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
  background: skyblue;
}

header.padded {
  padding-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</header>

<header class="padded">
  <h1>Another Heading</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: `h1` has `margin` by default, not `padding`.

Comment: oh my.... thanks. That hurts. haha.